# convert french date format

Tags: bash, date

I'm trying to convert french formatted date like : `16/12/14 11:40`

to : `12/16/14 11:40`

I tried this

```
echo "16/12/14 11:40" |cut -d "/" -f2,1,3
```

but fields are not printed on the good order. I also tried this :

```
echo "16/12/14 11:40" | awk  'BEGIN {OFS="/"} {print substr($1,4,2), substr($1,1,2), substr($1,7,2)}'
```

but now, time is no more specified.

and then tried this :

echo "16/12/14 11:40" | awk  'BEGIN {OFS="/"} {print substr($1,4,2), substr($1,1,2), substr($1,7,2)} {OFS=":"} {print substr($2,1,5)}'

but now date and time are printed on 2 differents lines :

12/16/14

11:40

Does anyone have the good way to do this ?

Thx

Comment: `cut` does not support reordering of the input fields. You can specify *which* fields it prints, but it will always print them in input order.

Comment: Would be great if we could convince people all over the world to use [a unique, unambiguous date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo "16/12/14 11:40" | sed -r 's/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\//\2\/\1\//'`

a short explanation of this. `-r` tells sed to use regexps. using this sed stores `([0-9]+)` matches internally making it accessible by a number representing the i-th match in replacement part. there we are now able to switch the numbers using `\2\/\1\/` with placing slashes between.

Comment: If you use a different delimiter than `/` for the `sed` fields, you don't have to escape them in the regex. `'s@([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/@\2/\1/@'` does the same and is somewhat easier to read.